# How to draw samples of two independent iid random variables from real and psudo random number generators?

Tags: probability, random-variables

There are 2 independent and identically distributed random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$. I need 1000 drawings of each one of these variables (in a monte-carlo simulation setting). Given this problem, i am confused if below are equivalent -

(a) draw 1000 samples for $X_1$ and then draw 1000 samples for $X_2$
(b) draw 2000 samples and then assign half to each one of them

Is (a) same as (b) in an ideal scenario when random numbers are truly random?

What happens when, in practice, we use numbers that are psudo random? should I use a different seed in random number generator when following method (a) [i will call this method (c)]. for example, set a random seed -> generate 1000 samples for $X_1$ and then set another seed and then generate another 1000 samples for $X_2$.? How will that compare when using method (a) when i dont change random seed or with method (b) where i generate 2000 numbers and just assign them equally to $X_1$ and $X_2$?

I am adding here work some work that I did using python numpy.
First i generated, random numbers using np.random

```
import numpy as np

sample_size = 100000

# method a - drawing samples for x1 and x2
np.random.seed(0)
x1_a = np.random.rand(sample_size)
x2_a = np.random.rand(sample_size)

# method b - drawing 2 * samples and then allocating to x1 and x2
np.random.seed(0)
x_b = np.random.rand(sample_size * 2)
x1_b = x_b[0:sample_size]
x2_b = x_b[sample_size:2 * sample_size]

# method c - drawing samples for x1 and x2 but with different random seeds
np.random.seed(0)
x1_c = np.random.rand(sample_size)
np.random.seed(120)
x2_c = np.random.rand(sample_size)

# now calculating correlations between x_1 and x_2
corr_a = np.corrcoef(x1_a, x2_a)
corr_b = np.corrcoef(x1_b, x2_b)
corr_c = np.corrcoef(x1_c, x2_c) 
print(f" correlations are: {corr_a[0][1]}, {corr_b[0][1]}, {corr_c[0][1]}")
```

this returns following

```
 correlations are: 0.004584252381322772, 0.004584252381322772, -0.0012275661688751346
```

Results make me wonder if :

1. is coefficient of .005 as witnessed in method a and b good
   enough to assume that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent with zero
   correlation
2. method c seems to be giving lower correlation. Is method c better in
   that case?

Comment: If your random generator is perfect, there is no difference. It is certainly not absolutely perfect, but then? Difficult to answer without a deep analysis of imperfection of this particular generator

Comment: If your assignment process is random, then the two methods should have the same effect.  But you would not expect identical samples from the two routes, unless perhaps your assignment process was assigning the first half to $X_1$ and the second half to $X_2$

Comment: Seed ? What seed ?

Comment: By the standard definition of "random variable," $X_1$ only has one value. Speaking mathematically, there is no such thing as "$1000$ drawings" from $X_1.$ But you appear to actually be talking about some kind of Monte Carlo simulation of the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2.$ You apparently want to explore some properties of the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$ by simulating the assignment of their values $1000$ times.

Comment: You can't expect to get _exactly_ $0$ correlation any more than you can expect exactly 500 Heads in 1000 tosses of a fair coin. // In R from `cor(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000))` I got
$ -0.03477459.$ Additional runs gave $0.02546233,
-0.0009571484, -0.03177299.$

Comment: @BruceET :  On your recent comment, i agree and its a possibility that zero will never happen. Is there any merit in thinking that method(c) is better than (a) /(b) based on lower coefficient or is that just due to chance?

Comment: Deleting that comment. // I'd guess chance.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are genuine random iid variables, a) and b) are equivalent.

But there is no "seed" for a random variable, so you must be dealing with pseudorandom numbers. In this case, with method b) there is some chance that due to unfortunate choices of seeds, the sequences coincide on some drawing, then on all those that follow. In particular, is the two seeds are the same, the sequences will be identical. With a single seed, this is less likely.

Comment: I have added some work above in my question. Can you opine if method (c) is better or I got these results because of chance and there is no difference between drawing using either of these methods?

Comment: @toing: my answer remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:**

For distribution $\mathsf{Binom}(10, .4).$ Computation in R. By using the same seed for the pseudorandom generator in R, you will get exactly the same results I did.  In R, `rbinom` generates random variables of the indicated number and with the indicated parameters.

Method 1:

```
set.seed(129)
x1 = rbinom(1000, 10, .4)
summary(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   3.000   4.000   3.941   5.000  10.000 
x2 = rbinom(1000, 10, .4)
summary(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    3.00    4.00    4.04    5.00    9.00
```

Method 2:

```
set.seed(129)
x = rbinom(2000, 10, .4)
x1 = x[1:1000]
summary(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   3.000   4.000   3.941   5.000  10.000 
x2 = x[1001:2000]
summary(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    3.00    4.00    4.04    5.00    9.00
```

Same results either way.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts in showing that method 1 and method 2 will give same results since pseudo random numbers follow a series.

Comment: I have added to my question impact from changing random seed when generating x1 and x2. Would appreciate if you can address that expect as well?